# No such file or directory using thunar

Tags: ubuntu-mate, error-handling, cd-command

This is really frustrating. Ubuntu Mate 18.04

The directory exists.

```
df
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              3492940        0    3492940   0% /dev
tmpfs              705964     1600     704364   1% /run
/dev/sda1      1798661892 23637776 1756722852   2% /
/dev/sda2       122478068 14868816  106342616  13% /media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75

total 740776
drwxr-xr-x 62 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 14:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root       4096 Aug 27  2020 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy          0 Sep 13 17:57 .addressbook
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Jan 20  2021 AppImage_Programs
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 16 21:26 .assaultcube
drwxrwxr-x  4 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 10:00 .audacity-data
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy       2032 Sep 30 09:47 .bash_aliases
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy       1207 Sep 30 09:50 .bash_aliases.zip
-rw-------  1 andy andy       7168 Sep 30 12:22 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 andy andy        220 Jul  7  2020 .bash_logout
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy         37 Sep 27 00:18 .bash_profile
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy       3866 Sep 27 00:50 .bashrc
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy       2019 Sep 28 08:03 .bashrc.zip
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy      12288 Sep 30 13:25 bin
drwx------  2 andy andy       4096 Dec 14  2020 .bl2
-rw-------  1 andy andy  757790880 Nov 21  2021 brasero.bin
-rw-------  1 andy andy        852 Nov 21  2021 brasero.cue
drwxr-xr-x 53 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 11:37 .cache
-rwxrw-r--  1 andy andy         73 Sep  9 12:21 Call_Script.sh
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Jul 29 16:22 .cddb
drwx------ 55 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 12:55 .config
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy        102 Sep  7 20:05 convert_png.sh
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Dec  1  2021 .cube2
drwx------  3 root root       4096 Aug 18  2020 .dbus
-rw-------  1 andy andy        326 Sep  8 21:36 DEADJOE
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 09:05 Desktop
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 11 08:31 .devilspie
-rw-r--r--  1 andy andy         23 Jul  7  2020 .dmrc
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 12:23 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy      20480 Sep 30 12:56 Downloads
drwx------  2 andy games      4096 Dec  1  2021 .emilia
-rw-r--r--  1 andy andy        662 Dec 14  2020 .foobillardrc
drwx------  3 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 09:57 .gconf
drwxr-xr-x 24 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 12:55 .gimp-2.8
drwx------  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .gnome2
drwx------  2 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .gnome2_private
drwx------  3 andy andy       4096 Feb 20  2021 .gnupg
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 19 07:22 .gphoto
drwx------  2 root root       4096 Aug 18  2020 .gvfs
-rw-------  1 andy andy     194204 Sep 30 11:37 .ICEauthority
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 13 12:45 .icons
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 27 13:17 ICONS
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy         82 Sep 13 21:19 Impt_Mutt_File.txt
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 27  2020 .java
drwx------  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .launchpadlib
drwx------  2 andy games      4096 Dec 22  2020 .lgames
drwx------  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .local
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy          0 Sep 30 14:17 ls.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 andy games        35 Jan  1  2021 .Maelstrom-data
drwx------  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 13 17:47 mail
drwx------  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 13 20:46 Mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .mkusb
drwx------  6 andy andy       4096 Dec 10  2021 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 23  2020 .mp3splt-gtk
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Jul 29  2021 .mplayer
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 10:04 Music
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Sep 13 21:30 .mutt
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy        385 Sep 13 20:55 .muttrc
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy        694 Sep 13 21:49 .muttrc.zip
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy        775 Aug 13 12:52 MyGuvcview_Profile.gpfl
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 16 21:23 .nexuiz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root          8 Sep 21 02:46 nfs-suspend-blocker.current
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        141 Sep 21 02:46 nfs-suspend-blocker.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         20 Sep 21 02:44 nfs-suspend-blocker.previous
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 30 09:55 OA_Folder
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy         70 Sep 15 00:10 other.sh
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 28 21:14 .parallel
drwxr-xr-x  6 andy andy       4096 Sep 28 16:55 Pictures
drwx------  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .pki
-rw-------  1 andy andy       1835 Sep 13 21:59 postponed
-rw-r--r--  1 andy andy        807 Jul  7  2020 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 Public
-rw-------  1 andy andy          0 Jul 26  2020 .python_history
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Dec 14  2020 .q3a
-rw-r--r--  1 andy andy      49152 Oct 17  2021 reminders.db
drwx------  2 andy andy       4096 Nov 26  2020 Replays
-rwxrw-r--  1 andy andy        767 Sep 16 22:46 restricted.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Sep 21 18:08 .rpmdb
drwx------  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .sane
drwx------  2 andy andy       4096 Nov 26  2020 Scores
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy         71 Aug 23  2020 .selected_editor
-rw-------  1 andy andy      23424 Sep 23 21:29 sent
drwx------  7 andy andy       4096 Sep 14 06:05 snap
drwx------  2 andy andy       4096 Feb 20  2021 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 andy andy          0 Jul  7  2020 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwx------  2 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .synaptic
drwxr-xr-x  5 andy andy       4096 Aug 23 14:09 Templates
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .themes
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 .thumbnails
drwx------  7 andy andy       4096 Sep 14 22:05 .thunderbird
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Jun 16 18:15 .ufoai
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy          0 Sep  2 13:30 UM_1804
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy        271 Sep 29 08:24 untitled
drwxr-xr-x  3 andy andy       4096 Aug 23 23:23 Videos
-rw-------  1 andy andy        929 Sep  8 21:34 .viminfo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        165 Jul  9  2020 .wget-hsts
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Aug 18  2020 Windows_Programs
drwxrwxr-x  4 andy andy       4096 Sep 23 10:45 .wine
-rw-------  1 andy andy         46 Sep 30 11:37 .Xauthority
-rw-r--r--  1 andy andy        131 Jul 11  2020 .xinputrc
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy       8562 Sep 16 19:12 .xscreensaver
-rw-------  1 andy andy      25852 Sep 30 14:15 .xsession-errors
-rw-------  1 andy andy      16196 Sep 30 11:37 .xsession-errors.old
drwxr-xr-x  2 andy andy       4096 Jul  6  2021 .xwelltris
drwx------  8 andy andy       4096 Sep 29 19:24 .zoom
```

How do I fix this?

```
cd: /media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/bin/: No such file or directory
Thunar: Failed to open "/media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/bin/": Error when getting information for file “/media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/bin”: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What do all the numbers and letters represent in your question? I also do not see a Ubuntu version in your question, please add.

Comment: the numbers relate to the UUID of the drive I presume... If you open the `Disks` utility you should see where the drive is mounted. Note that the mount point directory is case sensitive.

Comment: Is the partition in question mounted at all?

Comment: Yes it is mounted. @mook765

Comment: The df output does not prove that the directory exists. It does not show the existence of `.../home/andy/bin` Show us `ls -la` of  `/home/andy/`

Comment: @Organic Marble I what you requested  to my post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you `cd` into `/media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy`? Just in case: There is no confusion between `/home/andy` and `/media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy` is there?

Comment: Yes I could cd into that directory. @Organic Marble

Comment: @Organic Marble I will make a new post about using autofs. I need help with setting it up.